# Type order in function definition: difference between MinGW and VC++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mingw, mingw32

I notice that:

```
WINAPI ULONG Test()       // __stdcall unsigned long Test()
{
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
WINAPI int WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, ...)
```

are compiled correctly by MinGW compiler, whereas it fails with VC++ 2013 with:

> warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
>   IntelliSense: variable "ULONG" is not a type name
>   IntelliSense: variable "DWORD" is not a type name
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

With VC++, we have to swap the type order to make it compile:

```
ULONG WINAPI Test()

int WINAPI WinMain (...)
```

**Why does the other order fail with VC++ and compile with MinGW?**

Comment: Since  `__stdcall` is not part of the C++ standard, there's no particular reason why you should expect different compilers to behave the same.

Comment: Things like `__stdcall` are not part of the C++ language, they are *extensions*. And as such not all compilers actually support them, and the compilers that do support them might not do it the same way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok I see! I think this is the answer to the question, if you want to post it.